# Excel VBA Cell.Text vbNullString Issue

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code:

```
If cell.Text <> vbNullString Then
MsgBox "Hello"
End If
```

Some of the cells which have no text, but do contain a formula, would still trigger the message box. There is nothing visible in the cell and when I do

```
MsgBox cell.Text
```

the message box is blank. If I delete the formula, the message box is not triggered. The only difference I can find is that the offending cells have VarType 8, whereas other cells are of VarType 5. Some cells without text that are of VarType 5 do not trigger the MsgBox. The formula format is the same in both cell types.

What should I do to avoid triggering the message box for these cells? (MsgBox used for illustration, it actually executes other code)

Comment: Try `cell.Value` instead

Comment: This results in a type mismatch error

Comment: Where? in the MsgBox? Then do this `MsgBox CStr(cell.Value)`

Comment: MsgBox CStr(cell.Value) returns nothing for the offending cells

Comment: Does it help to include `Trim()`? Like `If Trim(cell.Text) <> vbNullString Then`. Just a thought, since cells could appear blank if they contain spaces, but wouldn't equal vbNullString either.

Comment: Yes that works, thankyou, still not sure why though. The formula in one of the offending cells is =IF(AND(ISBLANK(K85),ISBLANK(I85)),G85,IF(ISBLANK(I85),G85*K85,IF(ISBLANK(K85),G85*I85,G85*I85*K85)))

Answer (score -1):

I cannot find in Excel an object or property called `cell`. So `cell.Text` should give you a runtime error. You should use something like`ActieSheet.Cells(1,1).Value`.

That said, to compare a cell's content to the empty string, you can just use `""` (the empty string). You should compare it to the `Value` property, not the `Text` property as the latter is the formatted version.